# Is there a way to force replication that replicate only inserted and updated data?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I want to have a version of my db that contains all of data from first to now. If I use sql server replication, can I force that to ignore delete operation for replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of such feature.

And I would be surprised if one exists out of the box. What if instead of `UPDATE` one does `DELETE` and `INSERT`? Your target database will not be able to handle such change because it will not delete a row with some unique identifier (column value) `XXX`, and then will try to insert a new one with this identifier, resulting in a `unique key violation`.

**EDIT-1:** If what you want is the `only-recent` database in production and the `whole` database for audit, then maybe you should try different solution:

1. **Logical Delete and a View**: you change your `DELETE` logic (either by changing the DELETE command, or by using INSERT OF trigger) to only mark rows as deleted. Then you create a view that basically wraps your table but filters only those that are not deleted. Run all your SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE queries against this view instead. At the end also in your current solution you do mark "deleted" records as deleted somehow, right?
2. **Audit tables**: keep your history also in your main database, but in AUDIT (shadow) tables. Again you can do this with AFTER triggers almost non-intrusively.

Comment: I have a db with 400 tables. I can't put trigger on every table.

Comment: I do not think that the number of tables is limiting your usage of triggers. With little script you can create those triggers automatically. But this is more the question of your design. There is issue with logical delete in general: you might have FK constraint from "alive" table/row to a logically deleted one, which should not happen. But can you maybe elaborate on what you are trying to achieve with this kind of replication?

Comment: If you do not like triggers on your PROD database, whey don't you have them only on the REPLICA? so that instead of DELETE you either do nothing or mark those as deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Not a common scenario, see if this can help: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35648651/disable-delete-on-transac.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If you use Transactional Replication, you define what is done for updates, deletes and inserts on table articles that you publish.

*EDIT to add more detail:*
So, when creating a new Transactional Publication, under the Articles step (Figure 1), you can select all tables and "Set Properties of All Table Articles". The section under "Statement Delivery" (Figure 2) offers options on "delivery formats" for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements. You can set the format to "Do not replicate DELETE statements" or, for example "Call <stored procedure>", which can call a stored proc that sets a flag on each row that has been deleted on the Publisher.

> Figure 1
> [image: Articles Wizard Step]

> Figure 2
> [image: Article Properties Window]

With reference to Hilary Cotter's [answer on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a8364af-e9c0-4dcb-85a0-1b30ab41e20e/transactional-replication-insert-only-new-records).